# How to find a specific object from an array and return it?

Tags: java

I'm trying to figure out how to get the oldest car and return my Car object.

```
 public CarLot() {

    cars = new Car[5];

    cars[0] = new Car(2016, "honda", "civic");
    cars[2] = new Car(2017, "Lamborghini", "aventador");
    cars[3] = new Car(2000, null, "caravan");
    cars[4] = new Car(2010, "dodge", null);

    }
```

I'm confused here as my hold object isn't a Car object, super confused.

```
public Car getOldestCar() {

    int i = 0;
    int oldestCar = 3000;
    int hold = 0;

    while(i < cars.length) {
        if(cars[i].getYearManufactured() < oldestCar) {
            oldestCar = cars[i].getYearManufactured();
            hold = i;
        }
    }
    return hold;
    }
```

Comment: Javascript is not Java. This question has nothing to do with Javascript.

Comment: `hold` is an index of the oldest car. You should return `cars[hold]`.

Comment: of course hold isn't a Car. it's the index your car has in the array.

Comment: I am even more super confused that you get the return value when you are not incrementing the `i`.

Comment: what do I do at hold = i ?

Comment: I would change the int hold to Car hold , then assign hold - car[i].

Comment: Hi FiOna welcome to SO.  @Amongalen's answer is correct you can return cars[hold].  To answer your latest about what to do at hold = i you are already doing it. It should work because it is within the if() statement for the current indexed car being older.  In this case hold is the index of the oldest car so far.  I do like HarmandeepSinghKalsi idea even better.  That would change hold the oldest Car instance so far instead.  Either approach will work.

Comment: @holydragon you should be confused she gets a return value from running code that won't compile

Comment: Where is the definition of class Car? I fails to see the real problem. Where do you think it is?

Comment: @U.Windl why do you need to see Car in order to see what's wrong? It's pretty obvious. He is (trying to) returning the index, where he should return the Car that has that index

Comment: @Stultuske If the car doesn't matter, the problem can be reduced to finding any comparable (like `int`) in an array and returning it (which would not justify asking such a question (as it is trivial)).

Comment: @U.Windl the problem is he is returning hold, while he should be returning cars[hold];
the implementation of Car is not relevant at all

Comment: @Stultuske Even when the members of the array are `int`s, there's a difference between returning the array index and returning the array element.

Comment: @U.Windl of course. the point is, he wants to return an instance of Car. That's the returntype, and it's mentioned in the question. He has to return the correct instance from the array, not the index, that is his error. We don't need to see the implementation of the Car class to know that

Answer (score 1):

There are some missing things in questions or you may say incorrectly implemented.
Please find my program below which will return the car object

```
public class OldestCar {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Car[] cars = new Car[5];

        cars[0] = new Car(2016, "honda", "civic");
        cars[1] = new Car(2006, "honda", "city");
        cars[2] = new Car(2017, "Lamborghini", "aventador");
        cars[3] = new Car(2000, null, "caravan");
        cars[4] = new Car(2010, "dodge", null);

        System.out.print(new OldestCar().getOldestCar(cars).getName());

    }
    public Car getOldestCar(Car[] cars) {
        int i = 0;
        int oldestCar = 3000;
        int hold = 0;
        while(i < cars.length) {
            if(cars[i].getYearManufactured() < oldestCar) {
                oldestCar = cars[i].getYearManufactured();
                hold = i;
            }
            i++;
        }
        return cars[hold];
    }
}

class Car{
    int YearManufactured;
    String name;
    String model;


    Car(int YearManufactured, String name, String model){
        this.YearManufactured = YearManufactured;
        this.name = name;
        this.model = model;
    }

    public int getYearManufactured() {
        return YearManufactured;
    }

    public void setYearManufactured(int yearManufactured) {
        YearManufactured = yearManufactured;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }
}
```

I have created a `Car` class to solve this question. You can also cross-check with yours. I am printing the name of the oldest car. In the given case, it's `null`.

Some missing points I observed in question:

1. An array of cars is of size 5 but cars[1] is missing which will cause `NullPointerException`
2. `i` is not incremented in while loop hence loop will run continuously
3. `getOldestCar` should have car array as parameter to calculate oldest car

Hope this will help

Happy coding~

Comment: The initial maximum `oldestCar = 3000` is ugly. Wouldn't it be better to use the age of the first car (as match) and start the loop at the second car?

Comment: Yes, of course, it's better not to provide any hardcoded value. I just tried to keep the method the same as of original method asked in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is almost right.
In your method

```
public Car getOldestCar() { ... }
```

your return type is Car, but what you **actually** return is `hold`, which is of type int.
How do I know `i` is int? Easy, `i` is the index which you use in your `for` iteration, and every iteration you give `i` a value greater by one.

If you want to return a `Car` instead of `int`, there are two options:

- Declare `hold` to be of type `Car`. `int hold = 0` should be `Car hold = null`.
  Then, when you want to give `hold` a value inside the iteration, instead of giving it the value of `i`, give it the value of `cars[i]`, since that is the Car you're looking for.
- Second option, which would require you to change less code. In your last line, when you return `hold`, change it to: `return cars[hold]`. This will work because hold currently holds the index of the wanted car, so `cars[hold]` will give you the car you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public CarLot() {

    cars = new Car[5];

cars[0] = new Car(2016, "honda", "civic");
cars[2] = new Car(2017, "Lamborghini", "aventador");
cars[3] = new Car(2000, null, "caravan");
cars[4] = new Car(2010, "dodge", null);
}
```

---

```
public Car getOldestCar() {

int oldestCar = 3000;
Car returncar = new Car(); // -> you need to wirte a standard constructor: "public Car(){}"

for(Car x : cars) {
    if(x.getYearManufactured() < oldestCar) {
        oldestCar = cars.getYearManufactured();
        returncar = x;
    }
}

   return returncar;
}
```

Comment: this code won't compile. Car isn't array, remove the [i]. Also, why the '= new Car();' if no Cars in the list are made before that date (for instance, in an empty list), you'll return a non-existing car

Comment: yes car isnt array but CARS is a array (do you understand a for-each loop?), you can also just write Car return car; it doesnt matter

Comment: yes, I do. But I would recommend not acting all "defensive" against my "wrong" comment. The edited history of the answer remains visible. I was talking about your x[i].getYearManufactured... in your loop. x is a Car, not an array.
There is no need to be defensive/insulting, I merely pointed out some (valid) issues with your answer.